# Binary cryptogram from a friend

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

My friend sent me a "puzzle" in binary, and said that there are multiple steps to solving the puzzle, all of them including decryption. I translated the binary into text and he said that was a good first step, but I have absolutely no idea what cipher to use past that on the text. He said it requires a key and that the post he sent me should have all I need to solve the puzzle. Unfortunately, I'm completely stumped. I've been locked into using a Vigenere cipher because I believe he hid a keyword somehow, but I'm afraid I might be tunneling on that too hard. Can you help me figure out the next step?

---

Here's the full "puzzle" he sent me. Whether it's a copypasta, I do not know.

> Alright so to quell my boredom I have decided to make a puzzle,
>   whoever solves this puzzle and tells me the answer will get $100 cold
>   cash in their hand. For each day that passes I will give one hint but
>   the cash will drop 10 dollars for each hint. The first hint is free,
>   no this puzzle isn't just conversion that's just a step.
>
> **Puzzle #1**
>
> ```
>  01001001 01000010 00100000 01001000 01001110 00100000 01000001
>  00100000 01000011 00100000 01010110 01010101 00100000 01001011
>  00100000 01011000 01010100 00100000 00111001 00100000 01010000
>  00110111 01001011 00100000 01011010 01000111 01000111 00100000
>  01010010 01010000 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011
>  01010001 00100000 01001100 00100000 01001011 01001001 00100000
>  01000100 00100000 01011000 01010100 00100000 01010111 00110011
> ```
>
> Good luck.

---

Translating the binary to text yields: `IB HN A C VU K XT 9 P7K ZGG RP 20 3Q L KI D XT W3`

That's as far as I've gotten.

---

### **Updates**

---

**Hint 1**: The creator has posted a hint.

> It's something that makes him happy.

Comment: Do I get the 100$ if I solve it?

Comment: I don't know if there's actually a $100 prize. It's just part of the puzzle, possibly part of the code as far as I know.

Comment: Letter frequencies -- almost all the letters appear:
ABCDGGHIIKKKLNPPQRTTUVWXXZ  233790.

Comment: The $100 dropping by 10 each day makes me think of a cyclic Vigenere with a key of 100, but starting at 100 and subtracting 10.

Comment: do you have hints? It says you'd get some :P

Comment: 10 most likely represents not 10, but it's binary equivalent, 2. "\$" is also a symbol that denotes hex, leading me to believe that "\$100" represents the numeral 256.

Comment: @Excelseo so it would be 256 dollars and 2 dollars subtracted each day/hint.  Much better odds.  lol

Comment: He's posted an update on Reddit: 'Edit: He has provided a second hint. This is something that makes him "happy".'

Comment: EFJMOSY 14568 just making a note of what's "missing" as per Brian's character count, maybe they factor in?

Comment: @moonbutt74 Seems like from the Reddit page the OP has solved the second layer with a "smile cipher" (likely what the hint from Demesne was referring to). The cipher decryption tool can be found at: http://enisoc.com/smile.php but without knowledge of the key or more codes it will be impossible to solve. Indeed on the Reddit page the OP was told he/she was given the key to solve it.

Comment: Can someone provide a link to the reddit page?

Comment: Anything special about the message?

Comment: Decrypting the smile cipher using $4 as the key yields **,|end**. I don't know if that's helpful though.

Comment: @Pharap no i'm not :P

Comment: Has any progress been made since 2016?

Comment: Have you tried it in morse code or reverse morse code or reverse binary?

Comment: @Duck Morse code's sequence isn't that long....

Comment: Any more hints?

Comment: Your friend is weird.

Comment: So... uhhh... do we have yet to know the answer, still? :P

Comment: Has anyone found the original reddit post?

Comment: @Epiksalad Here's the Reddit post
https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/5kqkup/binary_cryptogram_how_to_reach_the_final_solution/

Comment: @Isusr No, it's not the original post. He says "In this site, it is said that the puzzle was from a reddit thread. Unfortunaltely, the reddit search tool is... not really performant, and I can't find this thread."

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> EmoSys?

Reasoning:

> Your letters after decrypting the binary, as shown by @Brian, combine to make **almost** every letter in the alphabet. Taking the letters not make, EFJMOSY, I can make the word: EmoSys. *I removed the numbers because I didn't think it would do anything related to a word that makes him happy*

Hint 2:

> It makes me happy; EmoSys is a company out of the Netherlands that specifically makes items that help people with depression, hence the 'makes me happy.' If he was depressed, EmoSys would help make him happy.

This was all I could come up with out of this cipher.